# How can I get the response to the questions from a google forms multiple choice grid?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, checkboxlist

I'm trying to get the choices that has been entered in a multiplechoice grid from Google Forms. I can get the rows, the columns but not the chosen choice by row.

[questions in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJhxO.jpg)

```
function Test_Field() {

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var process = ss.getSheetByName("Process TEST");
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Réponses au formulaire 3");
 process.activate();

 process.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), 
 sheet.getMaxColumns()).clearContent();

 var button = ("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
 var form = FormApp.openByUrl(button);
 var reps = form.getResponses();

 var items = form.getItems();
 var rep = reps[5];  //// I want only work on the 5 respons

 var l = 3;
 for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
  var index = items[i].getIndex();
  var l = l+3;
  process.getRange(l+1,1).setValue(i);
  process.getRange(l+1,3).setValue(index);
  process.getRange(l+1,3).setValue(items[i].getType());

  if(items[i].getType() == "GRID") {
    process.getRange(l+1,4).setValue("GRID");

    var testitem = items[i].asGridItem().getRows();
    var testitemcol = items[i].asGridItem().getColumns();
    var itemResponses = rep.getItemResponses();

    for (iii = 0;iii < testitem.length;iii++){
     var itemResponse = itemResponses[iii];
     process.getRange(l+1,iii+6).setValue(itemResponse);
     process.getRange(l+2,iii+7).setValue(testitem[iii]);
     process.getRange(l+3,iii+7).setValue(testitemcol[iii]);
                                            }
                                   }
     if (itemsrep[i] != null) 
     {process.getRange(l+1,5).setValue(itemsrep[i].getResponse())};
                                             } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this:
I checked if response came from Grid I was looking for item title and linked it to the response.

```
//Choose where from come your response
var formResponse = responses[i];
var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
var items = form.getItems();
for (var j = 0; itemResponses.length - 1; j++) {
  var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
  var tt = itemResponse.getItem().getType();
  if (tt = 'GRID') {
   var gridItmRows = itemResponses[j].asGridItem().getRows();
   var gridResponse = itemResponses[j].getResponse();
   for (var k = 0; k < gridResponse.length; k++){
//Set title - row's value
   sheet.getRange(counter, 1).setValue(gridItmRows[k]);
//set answer - column's value
   sheet.getRange(counter, 3).setValue(gridResponse[k]);
   counter = counter + 1;
   }
  }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: still not working. In the logfile I have "Response #6 to the question "Vraagjes" was "[Ja, Neen, Neen, null, Ja, null, Neen, null, Neen, null, null]". So I would like to have those values as I have had the titles by "var testitem = items[i].asGridItem().getRows();"

Comment: [Ja, Neen, Neen, null, Ja, null, Neen, null, Neen, null, null] is a string array that you can get by gridResponse =  itemResponses[k].getResponse(); where itemResponses  = formResponse.getItemResponses(); after that you can use gridResponse[i] to get responses (column values). It was missing at answer, I'm editing now.

Comment: thank you, finaly I did in an other way, but I keep your answer for the next time